# RSpec - A JSON text must at least contain two octets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Two failing specs after upgrading `rspec-rails (2.5.2 -> 3.8.1)` and `capybara (2.18.0 -> 3.10.1)`:

Not really sure what's going on here. Looks like text in the expectation is being truncated?!?

```
  let(:story_attributes) do
    {
      title:       'Edited title',
      description: 'Edited location',
      start_year:  '2001',
      start_month: 'December',
      start_day:   '5',
      end_year:    '2001',
      end_month:   'October',
      end_day:     '10',
      is_range:    true,
      cover_image: {
        url: 'http://placehold.it/edited.png'
      }
    }
  end

  ... 

  within 'section.story-cover' do
    expect(page).to have_text 'Edited title'
    expect(page).to have_text 'Edited location'
    expect(page).to have_text 'December 5th - October 10th, 2001'
  end
```

In first failed example (below) "Edited location" is being truncated.

In second example `expect(page).to have_text 'Edited title Edited location'` where only "Edited title\nEdited locat" is found.

Then there's this "JSON text must at least contain two octets" issue which may or may not be related but this used to pass before upgrading rspec-rails & capybara.ds

Thoughts?

```
RSpec Failures:

  1) Story editing published edit story
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)

     JSON::ParserError:
       A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:36:in `post_to_filepicker'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:18:in `convert_format'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:11:in `block in convert'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:10:in `each'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:10:in `convert'
     # ./app/models/images/image.rb:5:in `convert'
     # ./app/models/images/image.rb:20:in `enqueue_conversion'
     # ./app/services/story/updating_service.rb:14:in `update'
     # ./app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:58:in `update'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
     #   expected to find text "Edited location" in "Edited title\nLyla HoegerEditedDecember 5th - October 10th, 2001Download"
     #   ./spec/features/stories/editing_spec.rb:86:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Story editing private private story should be read after editing
     Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)

     JSON::ParserError:
       A JSON text must at least contain two octets!
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:36:in `post_to_filepicker'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:18:in `convert_format'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:11:in `block in convert'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:10:in `each'
     # ./app/services/converter/image_service.rb:10:in `convert'
     # ./app/models/images/image.rb:5:in `convert'
     # ./app/models/images/image.rb:20:in `enqueue_conversion'
     # ./app/services/story/updating_service.rb:14:in `update'
     # ./app/controllers/stories_controller.rb:58:in `update'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
     #   expected to find text "Edited title Edited location" in "Edited title\nEdited locat"
     #   ./spec/features/stories/editing_spec.rb:115:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Please provide your specs and the related code, not everyone is familiarized with changes so specific between versions. Thank you!

Comment: I added some more details but the expectation is pretty vanilla, in my opinion. Something else is going on, I think?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the big changes between Capybara 2.x and 3.x was that in Capybara 3.x text is returned as closely to what is displayed as possible.  This means that line feeds are now included in the returned text when they would display to the user - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/UPGRADING.md.  You either need to change your expected text to "Edited title\nEdited location" at spec/features/stories/editing_spec.rb:115 or if you don't care about the linefeeds you can use the `:normalize_ws` option => `expect(page).to have_text("Edited title Edited location", normalize_ws: true)`

Comment: This is great!  Thanks!  Where is the definitive source for documentation for using RSpec & Capybara?  I never would have found `normalize_ws` in my searching for a solution to this problem.

Comment: The docs - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara  are the best source for info - and the History.md file for a list of the changes.  There's a gitter page linked from the github for discussing things or just post here and someone will answer within a reasonable time.